# Starting a service from an activity

Tags: android, android-service

I have an activity, `MusicLauncher`, that should start up and start a new Service, `HeadsetService`. However, the service never starts. This is the MusicLauncher class:

```
public class MusicLauncher extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, HeadsetService.class));
        Toast.makeText(MusicLauncher.this, "Launching service...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.frazer.musiclauncher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MusicLauncherPopup"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:exported="true">          
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MusicLauncher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:exported="true">          
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".HeadsetService"></service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't start? Put some logs in services' onCreate method.

Comment: Put some logs on the Service class's onCreate and onStart methods and check if they appear.

Comment: I have a toast in the services onCreate method, it never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying service tag like below.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".HeadsetService" />
```

Instead of putting a Toast in your activity, put a Toast/Log in your Service `onCreate()` method and see whether it's appearing.
If you need more info, check this [link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

Answer (score 1):

maybe useful for newers! 
When you use more then one package `android:name` will be `com.package_name.` with (full package name) like this:

`<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.package_name.HeadsetService" />`